# Regular Expressions to Unmerge row entries

Tags: r, regex, split, pattern-matching

I have an example data set given by

```
df <- data.frame(
country = c("GermanyBerlin", "England (UK)London", "SpainMadrid", "United States of AmericaWashington DC", "HaitiPort-au-Prince", "country66city"),
  capital = c("#Berlin", "NA", "#Madrid", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
  url = c("/country/germany/01", "/country/england-uk/02", "/country/spain/03", "country/united-states-of-america/04", "country/haiti/05", "country/country6/06"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

                                country capital                                 url
1                         GermanyBerlin #Berlin                 /country/germany/01
2                    England (UK)London      NA              /country/england-uk/02
3                           SpainMadrid #Madrid                   /country/spain/03
4 United States of AmericaWashington DC      NA country/united-states-of-america/04
5                   HaitiPort-au-Prince      NA                    country/haiti/05
6                         country66city      NA                 country/country6/06
```

The aim is to tidy this so that the columns are as one would expect from their names:

- the first should contain only the country name.
- the second should contain the capital (without a # sign).
- the third should remain unchanged.

So my desired output is:

```
                  country        capital                                 url
1                  Germany         Berlin                 /country/germany/01
2             England (UK)         London              /country/england-uk/02
3                    Spain         Madrid                   /country/spain/03
4 United States of America  Washington DC country/united-states-of-america/04
5                    Haiti Port-au-Prince                    country/haiti/05
6                 country6          6city                 country/country6/06
```

In the cases where there are non-NA entries in the `capital` column, I have a piece of code that achieves this (see bottom of post).

Therefore I am looking for a solution that recognises that the pattern of the `url` column can be used to split the capital out of the `country` column.

This needs to account for the fact that

- the URL text is all lower case, whilst the country name as it appears in the `country` column has mixed cases.
- the text in the URL replaces spaces with hyphens.
- the url removes special characters (such as the brackets around UK).

I would be interested to see how this aim can be achieved, presumably using regular expressions (though open to any options).

---

**Partial solution when `capital` column is non-NA**

Where there are non-NA entries in the `capital` column the following code achieves my aim:

```
df %>% mutate( capital =   str_replace(capital, "#", ""), 
               country = str_replace(country, capital,"") 
              )

                                country capital                                 url
1                               Germany  Berlin                 /country/germany/01
2                    England (UK)London      NA              /country/england-uk/02
3                                 Spain  Madrid                   /country/spain/03
4 United States of AmericaWashington DC      NA country/united-states-of-america/04
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
transform(df,capital=sub(".*[A-Z]\\S+([A-Z])","\\1",country))

                               country       capital                                 url
1                         GermanyBerlin        Berlin                 /country/germany/01
2                    England (UK)London        London              /country/england-uk/02
3                           SpainMadrid        Madrid                   /country/spain/03
4 United States of AmericaWashington DC Washington DC country/united-states-of-america/04
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; I appreciate your solution has avoided using the `url` column, but unfortunately your solution isn't quite flexible enough to include the options around the possible entries in the columns. For instance it currently cannot handle the case of hyphens / special characters in the capital name itself. Also (perhaps slightly unrealistically, but important in my actual application) the possibility that there might be numbers in either the country or capital. I've expanded my base example to cover these.

Comment: I think working with the URL column should help in picking up any odd behaviour around numbers (in the last example the URL column picks up that one of the 6's belongs to the country, and the other to the capital). In my scenario it is a reasonable assumption that one of the intended entries in the capital column would never start with a special character (but could start with a number). Thanks again for your thoughts! I appreciate your solution worked well on the data I originally gave, but unfortunately it was hard for me to put into the example 'unit tests' for all the potential pitfalls!

Comment: Tis will work in all cases if the city name starts with a capital lettter.. no matter what is before it.. whether nu,bers or not.. the only exception being if there is a space then it will not recognise.. but as long as the city and the country name are together and as long as both of them starts with a capital letter then we will get the city name

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this and keep on refining until you get the (100%) correct results and then see if you can skip/merge any steps.

```
library(magrittr)

df$country2 <- df$url %>%
  gsub("-", " ", .) %>%
  gsub(".+try/(.+)/.+", "\\1", .) %>%
  gsub("(\\b[a-z])", "\\U\\1", ., perl = TRUE)

df$capital <- df$country %>%
  gsub("[()]", " ", .) %>%
  gsub(" +", " ", .) %>%
  gsub(paste(df$country2, collapse = "|"), "", ., ignore.case = TRUE)

df$country <- df$country2
df$country2 <- NULL

df
                   country        capital                                 url
1                  Germany         Berlin                 /country/germany/01
2               England Uk         London              /country/england-uk/02
3                    Spain         Madrid                   /country/spain/03
4 United States Of America  Washington DC country/united-states-of-america/04
5                    Haiti Port-au-Prince                    country/haiti/05
6                 Country6          6city                 country/country6/0
```